# Cómo cambiar con JS el vídeo en un reproductor Video

Tags: javascript, html, html5, video

Quisiera cambiar el vídeo al dar click en una de las opciones, tengo todos los sources de los videos guardados en variables. Hasta ahora el reproductor carga por defecto un video y cuando seleccionas un vídeo del ordenador lo reproduce.

HTML

```
    <video width="100%" height="auto" controls autoplay id="videoPlayer">
      <source src="<?php echo $variablesrc1;?>" id="videos">
    </video>

    <input type="file" name="file[]" class="file_multi_video" 
    accept="video/*">
```

JS

```
$(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function(evt) {
var $source = $('#videos');
$source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
$source.parent()[0].load();
});
```

En la parte de seleccionar videos a reproducir lo tengo así

```
<ul class="list-unstyled video-list-thumbs row">
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" title="<?php echo $variablename1;?>">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6fyDb3rks2o/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
        <h2><?php echo $variablename1;?></h2>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
        <span class="duration">03:15</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" title="<?php echo $variablename2;?>">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6fyDb3rks2o/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
        <h2><?php echo $variablename2;?></h2>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
        <span class="duration">03:15</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" title="<?php echo $variablename3;?>">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6fyDb3rks2o/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
        <h2><?php echo $variablename3;?></h2>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
        <span class="duration">03:15</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" title="<?php echo $variablename4;?>">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6fyDb3rks2o/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
        <h2><?php echo $variablename4;?></h2>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
        <span class="duration">03:15</span>
    </a>
```

Comment: debes agregar a tu pregunta los src de lo videos o como los manejas o almacenas para poder ayudarte de momento solo vemos miniaturas con nombres y tiempo pero sin referencia de src de videos!

Comment: @Bryro Hola si, perdona culpa mía vi ese fallo ahora. Pero veo que te apañaste con mi info y me ayudaste muchísimo

Comment: @Trauma perfecto, listo !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

> el video lo tomo del `href` del `anchor`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 let video = $("#videoPlayer")[0];
 let anchor = $("a");


 $(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function(evt) {
  let $source = $('#videos');
  $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  $source.parent()[0].load();
 });

 // asignamos un evento click a los anchor
 anchor.on("click", function(e){
  // prevenimos el comportamiento por defecto del anchor
  e.preventDefault();
  // asignamos como src del video el valor el href del anchor 
  video.src = $(this).attr("href");
  // cargamos el video
  video.load();
  // le damos play
  video.play();
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <video width="400px" height="auto" controls autoplay id="videoPlayer">
  <source src="" id="videos">
</video>

<input type="file" name="file[]" class="file_multi_video" 
accept="video/*">

<ul class="list-unstyled video-list-thumbs row">
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" title="<?php echo $variablename1;?>">
    <img src="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/poster_rodents_big.jpg?x81236" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename1;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/downtown-los-angeles.mp4" title="<?php echo $variablename2;?>">
    <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1035350/4080/i/950/depositphotos_40803427-stock-photo-downtown-los-angeles.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename2;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="http://learn.shayhowe.com/assets/misc/courses/html-css/adding-media/earth.mp4" title="<?php echo $variablename3;?>">
    <img src="https://static.posters.cz/image/1300/fotomurales/planet-earth-416x290-cm-premium-non-woven-wallpaper-130gsm-i55819.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename3;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" title="<?php echo $variablename4;?>">
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/2b/37/3c/ocean-blue-tenerife.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename4;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Duda resuelta 100% satisfactória con tu ayuda, muy clara y perfecta para lo que necesitaba! Gracias

Comment: Hola !, es posible hacer que reproduzca un URL Youtube?

Comment: si. pero para poder responderte con codigo debes hacer otra pregunta!

Comment: Vale gracias!, lo tengo aquí [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249705/como-reproducir-un-video-de-youtube-por-url-con-html-js]