# Como reproducir un video de Youtube por URL con HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html, video

en un post anterior de poder cambiar de vídeo con JS me dieron la respuesta perfecta.

Esta vez tendría la duda de si uno de los "src" que quiero reproducir al seleccionar es un URL de Youtube.

Tengo el ejemplo anterior de un compañero de la comunidad :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 let video = $("#videoPlayer")[0];
 let anchor = $("a");


 $(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function(evt) {
  let $source = $('#videos');
  $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  $source.parent()[0].load();
 });

 // asignamos un evento click a los anchor
 anchor.on("click", function(e){
  // prevenimos el comportamiento por defecto del anchor
  e.preventDefault();
  // asignamos como src del video el valor el href del anchor 
  video.src = $(this).attr("href");
  // cargamos el video
  video.load();
  // le damos play
  video.play();
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <video width="400px" height="auto" controls autoplay id="videoPlayer">
  <source src="" id="videos">
</video>

<input type="file" name="file[]" class="file_multi_video" 
accept="video/*">

<ul class="list-unstyled video-list-thumbs row">
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" title="<?php echo $variablename1;?>">
    <img src="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/poster_rodents_big.jpg?x81236" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename1;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/downtown-los-angeles.mp4" title="<?php echo $variablename2;?>">
    <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1035350/4080/i/950/depositphotos_40803427-stock-photo-downtown-los-angeles.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename2;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="http://learn.shayhowe.com/assets/misc/courses/html-css/adding-media/earth.mp4" title="<?php echo $variablename3;?>">
    <img src="https://static.posters.cz/image/1300/fotomurales/planet-earth-416x290-cm-premium-non-woven-wallpaper-130gsm-i55819.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename3;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" title="<?php echo $variablename4;?>">
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/2b/37/3c/ocean-blue-tenerife.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename4;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Por favor aclara tu pregunta, añade un enlace al soporte que te dieron anteriormente. Siendo sincero no entiendo qué quieres lograr.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, felizmente ya lo resolvieron. Para la próxima tendré en cuenta tu tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para reproducir los video de youtube requieres un iframe:

> **nota:** el snippets de **stackoverflow** no permite **iframe** por eso no lo podras ver aqui!

**version funcional:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bryr0/5c6op9rz/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // seleccionamos el  video
 let video = $("#videoPlayer");
    // seleccionamos el anchor
 let anchor = $("a");
    // seleccionamos el iframe
    let frame = $("#youtube");
    // embed youtube url
    let embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/";

 $(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function(evt) {
  let $source = $('#videos');
  $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  $source.parent()[0].load();
 });

 // asignamos un evento click a los anchor
 anchor.on("click", function(e){
  // prevenimos el comportamiento por defecto del anchor
        e.preventDefault();
        // optenemos el valor el href del anchor
        let href = $(this).attr("href");
        // creamos un regex para youtube
        let you =/(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([^"&?\/ ]{11})/i;
        // validamos que sea un video de youtube
        if (href.match(you)) {
            //obtenemos el id del video
            let idv = href.match(you)[1];
            // escondemos el reproductor de video html5
            video.css("display","none");
            // pausamos el video html5
            video[0].pause();
            // configuramos el iframe con el video de youtub
            frame.attr("src",`${embed}${idv}?autoplay=1`);
            // mostramos el iframe
            frame.css("display","initial");

        }else{
            // escondemos el iframe
            frame.css("display","none");
            // mostramos el reprodutor de video html5
            video.css("display","initial");
            // desconfiguramos el iframe para que el video se pause
            frame.attr("src",`${embed}`);
            // asignamos como src del video el valor el href del anchor
            video[0].src = href;
            //cargamos el video
            video[0].load();
            //le damos play
            video[0].play();
        }
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

 <video width="400px" height="auto" controls autoplay id="videoPlayer">
  <source src="" id="videos">
</video>

<iframe width="400px"  src="" frameborder="0" id="youtube" allow='autoplay' style="display:none;"></iframe>

<input type="file" name="file[]" class="file_multi_video" 
accept="video/*">

<ul class="list-unstyled video-list-thumbs row">
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" title="<?php echo $variablename1;?>">
    <img src="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/poster_rodents_big.jpg?x81236" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename1;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/downtown-los-angeles.mp4" title="<?php echo $variablename2;?>">
    <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1035350/4080/i/950/depositphotos_40803427-stock-photo-downtown-los-angeles.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename2;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9K7VfN4XPE" title="<?php echo $variablename3;?>">
    <img src="http://static.t13.cl/images/sizes/1200x675/1523274300-sencillo.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename3;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<a href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" title="<?php echo $variablename4;?>">
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/2b/37/3c/ocean-blue-tenerife.jpg" alt="video" class="img-responsive" height="130px" />
    <h2><?php echo $variablename4;?></h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
    <span class="duration">03:15</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Buenas ! el código nuevamente va perfecto gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Así:

Yo usé un replace porque:

URL de Youtube: https://youtu.be/**DYpOsgBdN6k**

URL embed: https://www.youtube.com/embed/**DYpOsgBdN6k**

Tuve que reemplazar lo que no está en negrita
con replace() así:
str.replace("https://youtu.be/","https://youtube.com/embed/")

Usé **br** para que todo esté vertical, antes de cada etiqueta

```js
function car(){
var x=document.getElementById("txt");
let str = x.value; document.getElementById("vid").src=str.replace("https://youtu.be/","https://youtube.com/embed/");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<br><input id="txt">
<br><button onclick="car()">Cargar video</button>
<br><iframe id="vid"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```